# Find Signed up User from redirect of AWS Cognito Hosted UI

Tags: amazon-cognito

I want to know which user has signed up on my Cognito hosted UI.
I configured everything accordingly to the AWS documentation.

When opened, the UI works just fine.
As soon as it comes to the redirect to my website it appends a UUID code like this:

https://example.com/signup?code=140ac1a7-aaaa-bbbb-cccc-180bcb7c55f0

But it seems that the given code has nothing in common with the user that was just created.
Where am I missing something?

Additional info: I'm working on a java backend, so I cannot use the JS SDK

I tried to change the response_type to `token` instead of `code` but then the hosted UI redirects me to:

https://example.com/signup?#error_description=unauthorized_client&error=invalid_request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UUID is the access code. With it u can get the access token which can provide you with the user information.
The documentation can be found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

And the request looks like this:

```
POST https://your-pool.auth.your-region.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&
client_id=your-code&
code=the-access-code&
redirect_uri=your-redirect
```